# How to send Jacoco code coverage report in email from jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a jenkins job setup, which generated the Jacoco code coverage for my maven project. Now, I want to send this report or a summary report for code coverage to my team members every time this jenkins job is executed.
Is there a plugin or any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Email Ext Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) for this. You can add an `Ant Pattern` to filter needed files.

```
emailext(
      subject: "SUBJECT",
      attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: "**/*.html",compressLog: true,
      body: "Test Email" ,to: adress@g.com)
```